# If $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ are linearly ordered sets and $|A_1|=|A_2|<\aleph_0$. Then $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ are isomorphic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> If $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ are linearly ordered sets and $|A_1|=|A_2|<\aleph_0$. Then $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ are isomorphic.

---

**My attempt:**

**Lemma:** Every linear ordering on a finite set is a well-ordering.

I will prove this theorem by induction on $n=|A_1|=|A_2|$.

For $n=0$, $A_1=A_2=\emptyset$, then $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ are clearly isomorphic.

Assume that the theorem is true for $n=k$.

For $n=k+1$, by **Lemma**, $<_1$ and $<_2$ are well-orderings. Let $a_1,a_2$ be the least elements of $A_1,A_2$ respectively. Then $|A_1-\{a_1\}|=|A_2-\{a_2\}|=n$, so by inductive hypothesis, there is an isomorphism $g$ between $(A_1-\{a_1\},{<_1} \cap (A_1-\{a_1\})^2$ and $(A_2-\{a_2\},{<_2} \cap (A_2-\{a_2\})^2$. We define $f:A_1 \to A_2$ by $$f(a)=g(a) \text{ for all }a\neq a_1 \text{ and }f(a_1)=a_2$$

Now we verify that $f$ is an isomorphism between $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$.

It's clear that  $f$ is bijective.

> I'm stuck at proving $a <_1 b \iff f(a) <_2 f(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$. Although I find this result is quite intuitive, I'm unable to formalize it. Any help is appreciated!

---

**Update:** I added the proof that $f$ is isomorphism.

Now we verify that $f$ is an isomorphism between $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$. It's clear that  $f$ is bijective.  Let $a,b\in A_1$.

1. $a <_1 b \implies f(a) <_2 f(b)$

If $a,b\in A_1-\{a_1\}$, then $g(a) <_2 g(b)$ by the fact that $g$ is an isomorphism. Thus $f(a) <_2 f(b)$.

If one element of $\{a,b\}$ equals to $a_1$, WLOG, we assume $a=a_1$, then $f(a)=f(a_1)=a_2=\min A_2 <_2 f(b)$. Thus $f(a) <_2 f(b)$.

2. $f(a) <_2 f(b) \implies a <_1 b$

If $f(a), f(b) \in A_2-\{a_2\}$, then $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f(b)=g(b)$. Thus $f(a) <_2 f(b) \implies g(a) <_2 g(b) \implies a <_1 b$ by the fact that $g$ is an isomorphism.

If one element of $\{f(a),f(b)\}$ equals to $a_2$, WLOG, we assume $f(a)=a_2$, then $a=a_1=\min A_1 <_1 b$. Thus $a <_1 b$.

Comment: You might as will take the inductive hypothesis to be that that $f$ is an $order$ isomorphism.

Comment: Hi @Driver8! On the basis of your comment, I have come up with the proof that $f$ is an isomorphism, and added it as an update in my post. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: You have shown that every finite set $X$ can be well-ordered. Now from this observe that $X$ has a largest element, $e$. Suppose that the claim is true for $k<n$, take a well-ordered set $X$ s.t. $|X|=n$ and consider $X\setminus \left \{ e \right \}$.

Comment: Hi @Driver8! I may be wrong, but I think that my approach is essentially the same as yours. Your approach takes out $e$, which is the largest element, while mine takes out the least one. If you don't mind, please verify my attempt!

Comment: You removed a point from $A_1$ but not from $A_2$, so you can't apply the inductive hypothesis. Consider the sets $A_1\setminus \left \{ e_1 \right \}$ and $A_2\setminus \left \{ e_2 \right \}$ where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the largest elements in $A_1$ and $A_2$, resp.

Comment: Hi @Driver8 , I wrote in my post that *there is an isomorphism $g$ between $(A_1-\{a_1\},{<_1} \cap (A_1-\{a_1\})^2)$ and $(A_2-\{a_2\},{<_2} \cap (A_2-\{a_2\})^2)$*. Maybe you overlook it?

Comment: I confess I really do not understand your proof. Please see my answer, where I show how I would do it,

Comment: Hi @Driver8 ! If you tell me where you don't understand, I'm happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how rigorous you want to be or how much set theory you know. Here is one approach:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered sets of equal cardinality. If $A=B=\emptyset$ then $A$ and $B$ are trivally order isomorphic.

Otherwise, let $|A|=|B|=n$ and let  $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ be maximal in $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Then, $|A\setminus \left \{ a \right \}|=|B\setminus \left \{ b \right \}|$ so applying the inductive hypothesis, we get an order isomorphism $f:A\setminus \left \{ a \right \}\to |B\setminus \left \{ b \right \}.$

Now $g:A\to B$ defined by

$$
g(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f(x) & \quad x <a \\
            b& \quad x =a
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

is an order isomorphism.

Another way to do this would be to define

$E:A\to n\in \omega$ by $E(a_0)=\emptyset$ where $a_0$ is the least element in $A$ and in general, $E(t)=\left \{ E(x):x<t \right \}.$ Then, $E$ is by construction an order isomorphism from $A$ to $n$, where, of course, $n$ is well-ordered by $\in.$ To finish,observe that the $same$ function works for $B$, so $A$ and $B$ are both order isomorphic to $n$, hence to each other.